# Installation of themes in Atom text editor failed

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

I got this error while installing the Hydrogen package in Atom. While installing themes in the Atom text editor, I get this message:

```
Installing “Hydrogen@1.20.0” failed.Hide output…

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0`enter code here`
gyp info using node@6.9.5 | darwin | x64
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.6.9/iojs-v1.6.9.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! install error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: This is most likely not a problem with node-gyp or the package itself and
gyp ERR! stack is related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad 
gyp ERR! stack network settings.
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/1l/vxym0w453j30qk41zk061kg00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/7CF8217B-AC3A-4C87-92A8-DEC78EC13071/d/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:193:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestError (/private/var/folders/1l/vxym0w453j30qk41zk061kg00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/7CF8217B-AC3A-4C87-92A8-DEC78EC13071/d/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:884:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at connectErrorNT (net.js:1022:8)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/private/var/folders/1l/vxym0w453j30qk41zk061kg00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/7CF8217B-AC3A-4C87-92A8-DEC78EC13071/d/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/1l/vxym0w453j30qk41zk061kg00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/7CF8217B-AC3A-4C87-92A8-DEC78EC13071/d/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "install" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.6.9" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--ensure"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/achal/.atom
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: As the error suggests, did you try changing the network settings, Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: no.... Without Any Proxy...

Comment: Try a `wget https://atom.io/download/electron/v1.6.9/iojs-v1.6.9.tar.gz` and see if it works..

Comment: Attention close-voters: tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic for Stack Overflow, per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Atom would certainly qualify for that.

Answer (score 0):

Two main things to try:

```
apm rebuild
```

Or

```
apm install hydrogen
```